# identifyiing or detecting overlapping contours c++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on object detection and the results of it are pretty good. The problem I'm facing is when two objects are nearer to each other they are detected has one. Please help me how to solve this. The below link will give a clear idea of it.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AIHohc4gX9SXpVNWNGaUVKZGs/view?pli=1

Comment: welcome to the world of non-trivial computer vision.

Comment: @Micka thank u, Can i expect the solution for this ???

Comment: you could place the camera in an angle where the cars can't overlap.

Comment: @Micka thank u, i shall consider that. Apart from that any other solution to work on it??

Comment: detect cars instead of "blobs". see trained detectors like HoG, LBP, Haar Detectors etc. Or invent something new. Probably none of those will give you a universal solution in short time.

Comment: about your original question: if you didnt know what a car is, how would you decide where the contours are overlapping in your image?

Comment: @Micka i have worked on vehicles colors to separate them from the background. And now, i'm thinking of coloring each contours separately and color should remain the same until contours move out of the frame. Now, when two different Colors meet or overlap they give rise to different color. Detecting this change of color will help me i guess ! Will this method work for me???

Comment: in your sample image both cars have the same color

Comment: @Micka Its not a problem for me if they are of same color. I can segment them from the background. Overlapping of objects occur when are close enough to each other and are detected as one. After segmentation i ll convert the image to binary and find contours. After this i'm thinking of coloring each contour with unique color when two different Colors meet or overlap they give rise to different color. Detecting this change of color will help me i guess !

Comment: with "convert the image to binary" you mean foreground segmentation => binary foreground information? And you find contours in the binary image? then you again have overlapping objects combined as a single binary contour. But try it... imho the color information isnt reliable enough for segmentation (either get over-segmentation or similar colored cars will be combined).

Comment: @Micka can u please suggest what other kind of segmentation can be used so that this problem doesn't pose.  So that all vehicles can be segmented, detected and number of vehicles should be counted.

Comment: I doubt there to be such a segmentation technique.

Comment: @Micka Sorry !! i mean segmentation of vehicles only. the later part i ll do.

Comment: try some simple background extraction. for example you could test the demo app of ViBe as a first test. But algorithm is patented.

Comment: @Micka i have worked on background subtraction using Gaussian and the results of it are pretty good. Have attached the results of it the link below. I want to segment the vehicles based on the color and try. Please help me out in this.         https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5AIHohc4gX9bW5ZSlBULUF4RGM/view

Comment: as I said: I doubt there is a working color segmentation for your task.